# How do I make Python plugins work in Pluma?

Tags: python, gedit

I'm trying to add the Python plugin *trailsave* to the text editor Pluma* (which is a Gedit fork) but the plugin doesn't show up in the "Active plugins" list in the Pluma preferences. Also, I have compiled Pluma with Python support. Any ideas?

```
$ cat ~/.config/pluma/plugins/trailsave.pluma-plugin
[Pluma Plugin]
Loader=python
Module=trailingspaces
IAge=2
Name=Trailing Spaces
Description=Makes trailing spaces very visible
Authors=Gustavo Noronha Silva <gns@gnome.org>
Copyright=Copyright © 2012 Gustavo Noronha Silva
Website=https://gitorious.org/gedit-trailing-spaces
```

To my understanding, as far as the plugin configuration file above is correct the plugin will be displayed in the list. My next task will be to rewrite the Python code for Pluma.

*<sup>The reason I switched to Pluma is because the client-side decorations used in Gedit in Debian 8 (stable) does not work with my window manager of choice (Blackbox).</sup>

Comment: It sounds like you are using Debian stable/jessie. I wish people would just say so. If so, why didn't you use the puma official binary package? Does that not have Python support?

Comment: @FaheemMitha Yes, as mentioned in the footnote I use Debian 8 (Jessie). I have compiled Pluma from source just to be sure I have an installation with Python plugin support. I have not been able to use third party plugins with the official binary package either.

Comment: If I were you, I'd ask on an official forum. This is clearly a specialist question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After printing out the plugin path from the source I found out that Pluma looks for plugins in `~/.local/share/pluma/plugins`. The `.pluma-plugin` configuration file is correct however.